# How to load not bundled *.vue file from node_modules?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, loader, node-modules

I wrote small Vue package for internal usage in my project. It contain some plugins (.js extension), which includes Vue single-file components with `<template>` inside (.vue extension).

So complete scheme looks like:

*Component of my current project <- not bundled Vue plugin from my package in node_modules <- not bundled Vue component from my package*

After starting Vue SSR with webpack I see this error:

```
/node_modules/my-package/src/components/image.component.vue:1    
<template lang="pug">
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

My Webpack rules (based on https://github.com/fenivana/vue-ssr-boilerplate):
:

```
{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: {
            postcss: [require('autoprefixer')()],
            loaders: {
              'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
              'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    },
```

I don't know how to deal with it. What's wrong? JS loader or Vue loader?

Comment: How are you calling or importing your component?

Comment: @Stephan-v I'm importing plugin in es6 style. Inside the plugin component imported in es6 style too. Usage of `require` doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you include more code in your question?  Might be helpful to see the components